# I'm curious about this pattern, Name and how can I do it with photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I see this pattern around for a while now and I don't know what Its name and if there any tips how I can do it using a filter or something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is not a Photoshop native filter, there are two solutions, or do
  it yourself, better in a vector application or use an [Online
  Mosaic Maker Tool](http://damienclarke.me/code/mosaic-maker) and download the result.

> The mosaic filter in Photoshop can be a very useful pixelation effect, but it's restricted to turning an image into a set of squares.
>
> This little app lets you use triangles, hexagons, bricks, cubes and other shapes, as well as adjusting size, rotation and more.

[image: mosaic]

- About the name is [Tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation), in this case **Triangle
  Tessellation**.

> A tessellation of a flat surface is the tiling of a plane using one or more geometric shapes, called tiles, with no overlaps and no gaps.